# ¿Cómo podría sacar el total de una columna en una tabla react bootstrap table? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

#### Editado

El problema principal era lograr sacar con el mismo componente, el total de una columna. **Al final de la pregunta** está el código con la solución, para un *pie de tabla* (*footer*)

```
import React from 'react';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';

const formatName = (cell, row, extra) => {
  let display = 'No disponible'; if (_.get(row, 'name')) { display = `${_.get(row, 'name')}` }
  return (
    <div>
      {display}
    </div>
  )
};
const formatPrice = (cell, row, extra) => {
  let display = 0 ; if (_.get(row, 'total')) { display = `${_.get(row, 'total')}` }

  return (
    <div>
      {parseFloat(display).toFixed(2)}€
    </div>
  )
};



const formatTotalPrice = (cell, row, extra) => {
  let display = 0 ; if (_.get(cell, 'total')) { display = `${_.get(cell, 'total')}` }

  console.log('TOTAL:  ', display)
  return (
    <div>
      {
        parseFloat(_.sumBy(display,'total')).toFixed(2)
      }€
    </div>
  )
}

class ChartInventory extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sortName: 'name',
    sortOrder: 'asc',
  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      sortName: this.state.sortName,
      sortOrder: this.state.sortOrder
    };


    console.log(this.props.analytics)
    return (
      <span>
        <BootstrapTable data={this.props.analytics}
          trClassName="table-row"
          ref="inventoryAnalyticsTable">
          <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField='total' headerAlign='right' dataAlign='right' dataFormat={formatTotalPrice}>Precio Total</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
        <BootstrapTable data={this.props.analytics}
          options={options}
          pagination={this.props.analytics.length > 50}
          trClassName="table-row"
          ref="inventoryAnalyticsTable">
          <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField='name' headerAlign='center' dataAlign='center' dataFormat={formatName} dataSort>Nombre</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='total' width='100' headerAlign='center' dataAlign='center' dataFormat={formatPrice}>Precio</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </span>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToprops = state => ({
  analytics: state.inventory.analytics,
});

export default connect(mapStateToprops, null)(ChartInventory);
```

Aquí una imagen del resultado 
[image: donde salen los ceros debería de salir el total]

#### Problema editado

```
import React from 'react';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';

const formatName = (cell, row, extra) => {
  let display = 'No disponible'; if (_.get(row, 'name')) { display = `${_.get(row, 'name')}` }
  return (
    <div>
      {display}
    </div>
  )
};

const formatPrice = (cell, row, extra) => {
  let display = 0; if (_.get(row, 'total')) { display = `${_.get(row, 'total')}` }
  return (
    <div>
      {parseFloat(display).toFixed(2)}€
    </div>
  )
};

class ChartInventory extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sortName: 'name',
    sortOrder: 'asc',
  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      sortName: this.state.sortName,
      sortOrder: this.state.sortOrder
    };

    const footerTotalPrice = [
      [
        {
          label: 'Total',
          align: 'center',
          columnIndex: 0
        },
        {
          label: 'Total value',
          columnIndex: 1,
          align: 'center',
          formatter: (data) => {
            let label = 0;
            for (let i = 0, dataLec = data.length; i < dataLec; i++) {
              label += data[i].total;
            }
            return (
              <strong>{label}€</strong>
            );
          }
        }
      ]
    ];


    console.log('ANALYTICS ', this.props.analytics)
    return (
      <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}>
        <div style={{ float: 'left', width: 780 }} padder>
          <BootstrapTable data={this.props.analytics}
            footer
            footerData={footerTotalPrice}
            options={options}
            pagination={this.props.analytics.length > 50}
            trClassName="table-row"
            ref="inventoryAnalyticsTable">
            <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField='name' headerAlign='center' dataAlign='center' dataFormat={formatName} dataSort>Nombre</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='total' width='200' headerAlign='center' dataAlign='center' dataFormat={formatPrice}>Precio</TableHeaderColumn>
          </BootstrapTable>
        </div>
      </div >
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToprops = state => ({
  analytics: state.inventory.analytics,
});

export default connect(mapStateToprops, null)(ChartInventory);
```

#### Imagen del resultado editada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Donde salen los 0 debería salir solo un total de la columna Precio

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo sumas directamente desde el modelo? Es decir, a la tabla le pasas los datos con `this.props.analytics`. Podrías tener un simple bucle que sumase esos valores

Comment: @PabloLozano ¿Te refieres desde el action? ¿exportar otra formula que recoja `this.props.analytics` lo añada a un array y lo vaya recorriendo y sumándolo y luego le paso el resultado?

Comment: Sí. No sé lo que tiene analitics, pero si es un array de datos podrías hacer `let total = this.props.analytics.reduce((acc,dato) => acc+dato.total,0);`

Comment: `this.props.analytics` tiene un Array de Objetos. La verdad es que ando un poco perdido, porque se esconde mucho código en este tipo de JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

He conseguido sacar el total, pero fuera de la tabla, lo ideal hubiera sido en una tabla o más ordenado.
Así quedaría el código:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';

const formatName = (cell, row, extra) => {
  let display = 'No disponible'; if (_.get(row, 'name')) { display = `${_.get(row, 'name')}` }
  return (
    <div>
      {display}
    </div>
  )
};
const formatPrice = (cell, row, extra) => {
  let display = 0; if (_.get(row, 'total')) { display = `${_.get(row, 'total')}` }

  return (
    <div>
      {parseFloat(display).toFixed(2)}€
    </div>
  )
};

class ChartInventory extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sortName: 'name',
    sortOrder: 'asc',
  }



  render() {
    const options = {
      sortName: this.state.sortName,
      sortOrder: this.state.sortOrder
    };

    console.log('ANALYTICS ', this.props.analytics)
    return (
      <span>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
          <div style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            Precio Total
          </div>
          {_.sumBy(this.props.analytics, 'total').toFixed(2)}€
        </div>
        <BootstrapTable data={this.props.analytics}
          options={options}
          pagination={this.props.analytics.length > 50}
          trClassName="table-row"
          ref="inventoryAnalyticsTable">
          <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField='name' headerAlign='center' dataAlign='center' dataFormat={formatName} dataSort>Nombre</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='total' width='100' headerAlign='center' dataAlign='center' dataFormat={formatPrice}>Precio</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </span >
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToprops = state => ({
  analytics: state.inventory.analytics,
});

export default connect(mapStateToprops, null)(ChartInventory);
```

Y así la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]